# Grouping rows on the basis of range

Tags: sql, oracle

How to group data on the specific range of time in oracle.

My data as below:

```
HHMISS  No_of_Sessions
010101  2
010102  3
010104  5
010107  2
010108  1
010110  6
010111  8
010113  1
010115  6
```

My requirement is to get number of sessions for every 5 secs.

```
HHMISS  No_of_Sessions
010100  10
010105  9
010110  15
```

Comment: Why are the output rows at "010101", "010105", and "010110"?  That is not every 5 seconds (1st interval is only 4 seconds)?  Why are the sessions at "010110" double counted in your output (they seem to be counted in the "010105" total and the "010110" total)?  Please clarify your desired logic.

Comment: That's my bad, I corrected that one.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is confusing because the results you posted do not meet the requirements you describe.

Here is what I *think* you are looking for:

```
SELECT lpad(floor(to_number(hhmiss)/5)*5,6,'0') grp, sum(no_of_session)
from test_data
group by lpad(floor(to_number(hhmiss)/5)*5,6,'0')
order by lpad(floor(to_number(hhmiss)/5)*5,6,'0')
```

This will group each input row into intervals of 5 seconds and then give you the number of sessions in each group.

Full example, with test data:

```
with test_data ( hhmiss, no_of_session ) as
(
SELECT '010101',  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '010102',  3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '010104',  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '010107',  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '010108',  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '010110',  6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '010111',  8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '010113',  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '010115',  6 FROM DUAL )
SELECT lpad(floor(to_number(hhmiss)/5)*5,6,'0') grp, sum(no_of_session)
from test_data
group by lpad(floor(to_number(hhmiss)/5)*5,6,'0')
order by lpad(floor(to_number(hhmiss)/5)*5,6,'0')
```

> ```
> +--------+--------------------+
> |  GRP   | SUM(NO_OF_SESSION) |
> +--------+--------------------+
> | 010100 |                 10 |
> | 010105 |                  3 |
> | 010110 |                 15 |
> | 010115 |                  6 |
> +--------+--------------------+
> ```

Comment: Many Thanks for the help.
Its Works.

Comment: Np.  Please consider accepting my answer if it has answered your question. That way the question is marked as answered so people don't waste time looking at it.